# How to convert command line string to an array?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a command line in a string variable (this is not my program's parameters, I got it somewhere else):

```
cmd_line = "app.exe --a value -b \"this is a quoted string\"";
```

How i can convert this command line to an array?

```
res = ["app.exe", "--a", "value", "-b", "this is a quoted string"]
```

There is a winapi function [CommandLineToArgvW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776391(v=vs.85).aspx). There is an equivalent in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shlex.split()` does exactly that: https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html

Comment: Thanks. But this may fail sometimes on Windows  because special characters, like '>', '<'  are escaped in different way on Windows.

Comment: My bad, I overlooked the fact that your question was Windows-specific.